# improve speed when reading a binary file

Tags: python, performance, numpy, binaryfiles

I have a large binary file that I want to read in an array.
The format of the binary files is:

- there is an extra data of 4 bytes at the start and end of each row that I'm not using;
- in between I have 8 bytes values

I'm doing it like this:

```
        # nlines - number of row in the binary file
        # ncols - number of values to read from a row

        fidbin=open('toto.mda' ,'rb'); #open this file
        temp = fidbin.read(4)  #skip the first 4 bytes
        nvalues = nlines * ncols   # Total number of values

        array=np.zeros(nvalues,dtype=np.float)

        #read ncols values per line and skip the useless data at the end
        for c in range(int(nlines)): #read the nlines of the *.mda file
            matrix = np.fromfile(fidbin, np.float64,count=int(ncols)) #read all the values from one row
            Indice_start = c*ncols
            array[Indice_start:Indice_start+ncols]=matrix
            fidbin.seek( fidbin.tell() + 8) #fid.tell() the actual read position + skip bytes (4 at the end of the line + 4 at the beginning of the second line)
       fidbin.close()
```

It works well but the problem is that is very slow for large binary file.
Is there a way to increase the reading speed of the binary file?

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a structured data type and read the file with a single call to [`numpy.fromfile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html).  For example, my file `qaz.mda` has five columns of floating point values between the four byte markers at the start and end of each row.  Here's how you can create a structured data type and read the data.

First, create a data type that matches the format of each row:

```
In [547]: ncols = 5

In [548]: dt = np.dtype([('pre', np.int32), ('data', np.float64, ncols), ('post', np.int32)])
```

Read the file into a structured array:

```
In [549]: a = np.fromfile("qaz.mda", dtype=dt)

In [550]: a
Out[550]: 
array([(1, [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], 0),
       (2, [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0], 0),
       (3, [10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0], 0),
       (4, [15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0], 0),
       (5, [20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0], 0)], 
      dtype=[('pre', '<i4'), ('data', '<f8', (5,)), ('post', '<i4')])
```

Pull out just the data that we want:

```
In [551]: data = a['data']

In [552]: data
Out[552]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
       [ 15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.]])
```

---

You could also experiment with [`numpy.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to see if it improves performance:

```
In [563]: a = np.memmap("qaz.mda", dtype=dt)

In [564]: a
Out[564]: 
memmap([(1, [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], 0),
       (2, [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0], 0),
       (3, [10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0], 0),
       (4, [15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0], 0),
       (5, [20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0], 0)], 
      dtype=[('pre', '<i4'), ('data', '<f8', (5,)), ('post', '<i4')])

In [565]: data = a['data']

In [566]: data
Out[566]: 
memmap([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
       [ 15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.]])
```

Note that `data` above is still a memory-mapped array.  To ensure that the data is copied to an array in memory, `numpy.copy` can be used:

```
In [567]: data = np.copy(a['data'])

In [568]: data
Out[568]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
       [ 15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.]])
```

Whether or not that is necessary depends on how you will use the array in the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!!  .... the speed increase is amazing from 16 sec to 0.18 sec