# Read binary flatfile and skip bytes

Tags: python, numpy

I have a binary file that has data organized into 400 byte groups. I want to build an array of type `np.uint32` from bytes at position 304 to position 308. However, I cannot find a method provided by NumPy that lets me select which bytes to read, only an initial offset as defined in `numpy.fromfile`.

For example, if my file contains 1000 groups of 400 bytes, I need an array of size 1000 such that:

```
arr[0] = bytes 304-308
arr[1] = bytes 704-708
...
arr[-1] = bytes 399904 - 399908
```

Is there a NumPy method that would allow me to specify which bytes to read from a buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to rephrase what you are looking for (slightly), is to say you want to read `uint32` numbers starting at offset 304, with a stride of 400 bytes. [`np.fromfile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) does not provide an argument to insert custom strides (although it probably should). You have a couple of different options going forward.

The simplest is probably to load the entire file and subset the column you want:

```
data = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.uint32)[304 // 4::400 // 4].copy()
```

If you want more control over the exact positioning of the bytes (e.g., if the offset or block size is not a multiple of 4), you can use structured arrays instead:

```
dt = np.dtype([('_1', 'u1', 304), ('data', 'u4'), ('_2', 'u1', 92)])
data = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=dt)['data'].copy()
```

Here, `_1` and `_2` are used to discard the unneeded bytes with 1-byte resolution rather than 4.

Loading the entire file is generally going to be much faster than seeking between reads, so these approaches are likely desirable for files that fit into memory. If that is not the case, you can use memory mapping, or an entirely home-grown solution.

Memory maps can be implemented via Pythons [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) module, and wrapped in an [`ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) using the `buffer` parameter, or you can use the [`np.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) class that does it for you:

```
mm = np.memmap(filename, dtype=np.uint32, mode='r', offset=0, shape=(1000, 400 // 4))
data = np.array(mm[:, 304 // 4])
del mm
```

Using a raw `mmap` is arguably more efficient because you can specify a strides and offset that look directly into the map, skipping all the extra data. It is also better, because you can use an offset and strides that are not multiples of the size of a `np.uint32`:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f, mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mm:
    data = np.ndarray(buffer=mm, dtype=np.uint32, offset=304, strides=400, shape=1000).copy()
```

The final call to `copy` is required because the underlying buffer will be invalidated as soon as the memory map is closed, possibly leading to a segfault.

Comment: Where did you get values like 75, 100, (250, 100)?

Comment: @datta. 300/4, 400/4, 1000/4. 75 should actually be 76 since the offset is 304

Comment: @datta. I've made it explicit. 250 should have been 1000. It's just the block count.

Comment: While this works, I've found it slower than using `np.fromfile` and a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). Then I can just index and copy like: `np.fromfile(f, dtype=my_dtype)['data'].copy()` It is very similar to the top answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119687/improve-speed-when-reading-a-binary-file) post where I can exclude all the remaining data by field names.

Comment: @datta. Is a structured array faster than `np.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.uint32)[304 // 4::400 // 4]`? Also, it's definitely going to be faster to read the entire file. Using a memory map is slow-ish, but it lets you read files that are prohibitively large without crashing.

Comment: On my system those methods ran in the same amount of time. As for the memory map speed, its clearly a tradeoff for lower memory footprint. I'll still select the answer as you did answer my question and it works.